# Synapse - Notebook not working from Pipeline

Tags: scala, databricks, azure-synapse

I have a notebook in Azure Synapse that reads parquet files into a data frame  using the synapsesql function and then pushes the data frame contents into a table in the SQL Pool.

Executing the notebook manually is successful and the table is created and populated in the Synapse SQL pool.

When I try to call the same notebook from an Azure Synapse pipeline it returns successful however does not create the table. I am using the Synapse Notebook activity in the pipeline.

What could be the issue here?

I am getting deprecated warnings around the synapsesql function but don't know what is actually deprecated.

The code is below.

```
%%spark

val pEnvironment = "t"
val pFolderName = "TestFolder"


val pSourceDatabaseName = "TestDatabase"
val pSourceSchemaName = "TestSchema"

val pRootFolderName = "RootFolder"
val pServerName = pEnvironment + "synas01"
val pDatabaseName = pEnvironment + "syndsqlp01"
val pTableName = pSourceDatabaseName + "" + pSourceSchemaName + "" + pFolderName


// Import functions and Synapse connector
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
import com.microsoft.spark.sqlanalytics.utils.Constants
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.
import org.apache.spark.sql.SqlAnalyticsConnector.

// Get list of "FileLocation" from control.FileLoadStatus
val fls:DataFrame = spark.read.
synapsesql(s"${pDatabaseName}.control.FileLoadStatus").
select("FileLocation","ProcessedDate")

// Read all parquet files in folder into data frame
// Add file name as column
val df:DataFrame = spark.read.
parquet(s"/source/${pRootFolderName}/${pFolderName}/").
withColumn("FileLocation", input_file_name())

// Join parquet file data frame to FileLoadStatus data frame
// Exclude rows in parquet file data frame where ProcessedDate is not null
val df2 = df.
join(fls,Seq("FileLocation"), "left").
where(fls("ProcessedDate").isNull)

// Write data frame to sql table
df2.write.
option(Constants.SERVER,s"${pServerName}.sql.azuresynapse.net").
synapsesql(s"${pDatabaseName}.xtr.${pTableName}",Constants.INTERNAL)
```

Comment: Is your workspace publish up to date? If not, you could be executing a different version manually (up to date) vs from your pipeline (out of sync).

Comment: Yup, the latest version is published.
My first thoughts were a mismatch in versions or a permissions issues. But no matter how much access I give it I still have the same issue. I tested it in an environment without source control to check it's not a branch issue and to make publishing quicker and still the same problem.

Comment: Under inputs I can see the parquet files.
Under outputs I get this error:
There has an _BlobNotFound_ error be thrown, please check document to know more details.  

Based on that I would say the error is likely in the last section with df.write. and for some reason when running the notebook through a pipeline it needs some access I haven't given it?  

The data lake is associated with synapse and the synapse resource has contributor and storage blob contributor against the data lake.

Comment: I have isolated the issue. I still don't have a way to resolve it.
When I turn off the firewall on the data lake it works successfully.
This isn't a resolution. Beyond whitelisting all the IR IP ranges, how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This case happens often and to get the output after pipeline execution. Follow the steps mentioned.

1. Pick up the Apache Spark application name from the output of pipeline
2. Navigate to Apache Spark Application under Monitor tab and search for the same application name .
3. These 4 tabs would be available there: Diagnostics,Logs,Input data,Output data
4. Go to Logs ad check 'stdout' for getting the required output.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ydEXCVVGAiY

Check the above video link for detailed live procedure.

Comment: This did not answer the question. It appears that the Synapse pipeline Integration Runtime is being blocked by the Data Lake firewall. How do I fix this?, Synapse already has storage contributor to the Data Lake.

Comment: For on demand firewall opening the following link can be useful. https://azdataguy.com/blog/adfaccessingsynapse

Refer the below link also for enabling the firewall:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/security-and-access-control-troubleshoot-guide?tabs=data-factory

The following are the security considerations which may be helpful for you.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-movement-security-considerations

Answer (score 0):

We had a lot of pipelines in Synapse fail at my org.

Error codes to search:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: not existed channel
Error: Interpreter died:

Root cause, Spark version recently got updated.
The Apache Spark pools in Synapse were upgraded to the newest version
Pipelines started failing, hit notebooks and die

Issue (I believe) is that the Apache Spark configuration lives on the Notebook Activity in the pipeline. No way to directly update spark version for the notebook.

Solution: Change the Apache Spark "Spark Pool" config in the Settings on the Notebook Activity in the pipeline to a different pool, publish. Change it back to the original pool, publish. This forces the config with the spark version to update.

This solution fixed our pipelines containing notebooks with minimal effort.